# error: The 'python-dateutil' distribution was not found and is required by Mathics

Tags: python, pip, mathics

Hello i am trying to install mathics 
python3 setup.py  install --user
but i get this 
error: The 'python-dateutil' distribution was not found and is required by Mathics

and when i try to install date util i get this

```
root@thodo-Inspiron-15-3567:/home/thodo/Documents/Mathics-master# pip install python-dateutil
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.4)
```

can somebody help install mathics thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is numerous references in your output to python 2.7, hence your `pip` is installing to `python 2.7`.

To install to `python3`, simply use

```
python3 -m pip install python-dateutil
```

Comment: Τhank you very much i did as you say , and i did the same thing for sympy and mpmath, but now i have another problem .

Comment: Please post a new question for the new issue